# Get values from grid cell?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I'm trying to get the value of a certain column cell but with no luck. Here is my makeup of the grid:

```
 Ext.apply(this, {                
            xtype: 'grid',
            selModel: {
                mode: 'MULTI'
            },
            columnLines: true,
            store: Ext.create('TheGrid.store.GridDetail'),
            columns: [
                {text: 'FirstName', dataIndex: 'first_name', cellWrap: true, width: 75},
                {text: 'LastName', dataIndex: 'last_name', cellWrap: true, width: 100},
                {text: 'Comment', dataIndex: 'comment', cellWrap: true, flex:1, minWidth: 200},
            ],
```

I've tried to get the cell value by doing so:

```
 var grid_results = function(header_name, row) {
     var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid=itemId=gridID]')[0];
     return grid.getStore().data.items[0].raw['FirstName'];
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `get` method to obtain the value of a specified field in the `model`

ie:
`grid.getStore().data.items[0].get('first_name')`

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o2u)

Comment: Or `grid.getStore().getAt(0).get('first_name')`